# nav2d and Turtlebot

Tags: ros, exploration, turtlebot, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm looking to use nav2d package(wiki.ros.org/nav2d) with my turtlebot. But i have no idea how to mapping (or config) nav2d with turtlebot. So has anyone experienced this problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188209/nav2d-and-turtlebot/) by [hades](https://answers.ros.org/users/19822/hades/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-30**:
I guess that nav2d is simulator because there is stage_ros in part of How to start. I don't try it, but I think that you just replace robot model into turtlebot.

**Comment by [hades](https://answers.ros.org/users/19822/hades/) on 2014-07-30**:
Hi Ken, thanks for your answer. I edited file tutorial3.launch and it worked. But It has errors below:

- Could not get robot position: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.
- Exploration failed, could not get current position.
  So, Do you have any ideas?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-30**:
I think relationship between map and robot is not described  on tutorial3.launch. So, robot can't get its position. I guess that. As I don't read tutorial3.launch, I can't answer precisely. I recommend that you will check other launch files about turtlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

the nav2d package should be possible to use on any robot moving on a plane. The examples all use stage simulation for demonstration, but we used it on Pioneer robots as well. For a start I suggest you try to apply tutorial1 to your robot. You have to replace stage with your robot-driver. The RobotOperator generates a geometry_msgs::Twist, which is common in ROS to control any type of robot. If your driver uses this message-type, you can connect it directly. If this works, you can add navigation and mapping step by step following tutorials 2 and 3.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0